# undefined local variable or method `employee_params' for #<EmployeesController:0x37b7f68>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Controller

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController

  def new 
    @employee = Employee.new
  end

  def create 

    @employee = Employee.new(employee_params) 

    if @employee.save 
      format.html { redirect_to @employee, notice: 'Status was successfully created.' } 
    else 
      render "new" 
    end

    private

    def employee_params
      params.require(:employee).permit(:firstname, :lastname) 
    end 

  end 

end
```

models/employee.rb

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base 

  attr_accessor :firstname, :lastname

end
```

new.html.erb

```
Enter new information

<hr>

<%= form_for @employee do |f| -%>

FirstName:<%= f.text_field :firstname%><br />

LastName :<%= f.text_field :lastname%><br />

<%= f.submit "submit"%>

<% end %>
```

my output:

http://grab.by/DA3A

this is my screenshot..please help me to figure out this problem.

Comment: Which rails version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

You mistyped it (in your controller) bro. It should be like:

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController

  def new 
    @employee = Employee.new
  end

  def create 

    @employee = Employee.new(employee_params) 

    if @employee.save 
      format.html { redirect_to @employee, notice: 'Status was successfully created.' } 
    else 
      render "new" 
    end
  end 

    private

      def employee_params
        params.require(:employee).permit(:firstname, :lastname) 
      end 

end
```

I don't think I need to elaborate this :)